# Is it okay to say "Why do I should prefer this university?"

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Someone who claims that his English is perfect has used this sentence a few minutes ago. **"Why do I should prefer this university?"** It doesn't seem correct to me. Is it okay to use DO with SHOULD like that? Thank you.

Comment: It probably was a slip of the tongue. Sometimes I say, "Why do uh...should I do this?" Also, you should have said either, "Someone... **has used** this sentence **(before)**" or "Someone... **used** this sentence **a few minutes ago**." If you say "a few minutes ago", use the simple past. If the you want to convey an unknown or unspecific time in the past, then the present perfect is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "why do I should prefer this university?" is not grammatically correct.

The verb "should" is modal, and so it is used to form the question.

> Why should I prefer this university?

Compare

> I should not eat that cake.  (correct)
>
> I do not should eat that cake (incorrect)
>
> Can you help me? (correct)
>
> Do you can help me? (incorrect)